# py.test collection changes results

Tags: python, testing, sympy, pytest

I've been working on getting better py.test support with the [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) project and have run into a strange problem where it appears that the py.test collection process is changing the results of a test.

If I specify the test file explicity, the test passes (there's a few test which have exhibit this behavior but I've just selected one)

```
$ py.test sympy/physics/vector/tests/test_frame.py -k test_coordinate_vars -v --showlocals
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.1 -- py-1.4.25 -- pytest-2.6.3 --     /home/ptb/miniconda3/bin/python3
architecture: 64-bit
cache:        yes
ground types: python 

collected 4 items 

sympy/physics/vector/tests/test_frame.py::test_coordinate_vars PASSED

================ 3 tests deselected by '-ktest_coordinate_vars' ================
==================== 1 passed, 3 deselected in 2.12 seconds ====================
```

If I just specify the directory rather than the file, I get the following error

```
$ py.test sympy/physics/vector/tests -k test_coordinate_vars -v
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.1 -- py-1.4.25 -- pytest-2.6.3 -- /home/ptb/miniconda3/bin/python3
architecture: 64-bit
cache:        yes
ground types: python 

collected 39 items 

sympy/physics/vector/tests/test_frame.py::test_coordinate_vars FAILED

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________________ test_coordinate_vars _____________________________

    def test_coordinate_vars():
        """Tests the coordinate variables functionality"""
>       assert CoordinateSym('Ax', A, 0) == A[0]
E       assert Ax == A_x
E        +  where Ax = CoordinateSym('Ax', A, 0)

sympy/physics/vector/tests/test_frame.py:12: AssertionError
                                DO *NOT* COMMIT!                                
=============== 38 tests deselected by '-ktest_coordinate_vars' ================
=================== 1 failed, 38 deselected in 0.22 seconds ====================
```

Note that the 'A' in question is declared at the top of the file outside of any function/class definitions.  If I move the declaration of 'A' into the function than both uses pass but I would really like to understand what is going on since we make use of lots of module level variables declared at the top of our testing files.

Can someone shed some light on what's going on or point me to the relevant portion of the docs?

**UPDATE**

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22769477/3357105) to a slightly different question I've come up with the following that seems a better/easier solution compared to moving 'A' into every test_function in the file:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def global_vars(request):
    request.function.__globals__['A'] = ReferenceFrame('A')
```

If there are solutions that don't involve messing with global namespaces I would be happy to know them though. (As well as the cause of the original failure)

**UPDATE2**

Turns out this is due a caching bug involving `ReferenceFrame` in sympy.  Since the cache is global, it inadvertently allowed setup code from one file to corrupt some of the data in the test file which was run.

Comment: If that's your fix then that means some tests are messing with the state of `A`. If possible, define a new `ReferenceFrame('A')` in each test case (to completely separate the states) or go through the code to see where the internal state of `A` is being modified. It can be a subtle thing but that's essentially what's going on.

Comment: But in both cases only _one_ test is run.  And if I run all tests in `test_frame.py` they all pass if I specify the file explicitly.  The failure only occurred if I specified the directory (which contains other test_*py files) rather than the explicit file.  That's the part that doesn't make sense to me.  Wouldn't that mean that some sort of setup code from the deselected tests in other files is messing with the file-level variables in test_frame.py?