# Only in py.test file, usage of a nested(word?) imported variable/function fails with NameError

Tags: python-2.7, import, pytest, nameerror

I have a python structure like this:

```
mymodule/
globalconfig.py # variables to set environment, etc
work.py # has: from mymodule.globalconfig import * 
__init__.py

tests/
testspart1/
test_work.py # has:  from mymodule.work import *
```

From inside work.py, all is well and I can access my global config variables and functions. 
From inside test_work.py, I cannot access those variables, even if I add a second import,

```
from mymodule.globalconfig import *
```

Why is this? I wanted to use the same syntax as used in my modules.
thank you!

I am using py2.7 and, to get nice rspec-style outputs and verbose diffs,

```
pytest --spec -vv
```

Ref;
1.This answer reminded me I could use another format of import. If there are no other answers I will post my workaround. [how to share a variable across modules for all tests in py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768976/how-to-share-a-variable-across-modules-for-all-tests-in-py-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import syntax that worked for me was directly importing the nested python file in addition to importing the file under test.

```
from mymodule.work       import * 
import mymodule.globalconfig as myconfigs
```

I assume it's a name clash or import circularity issue, but I could not figure out what the problem was. It took me a while so I wanted to be sure to post the solution for future me and others.