# In pytest how do I temporarily disable capture in a class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

In pytest (3.04; python 3.4) I'm trying to disable output capture under certain circumstances.  I'm trying to follow the example on [this doc page](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html).  However, I'm unable to specify capsys as a funcarg.  As a follow-up, I'd like to accept both funcarg and on-funcarg arguments so that I can use a class method that takes one or more normal arguments. How can I do that?

Ideally, this class method would work:

```
    def always_print(self, message, capsys):
        with capsys.disabled():
            print(message)
```

But, I can't even get this to work:

```
def always_print(capsys):
    with capsys.disabled():
        print('FIXME')
```

Getting the error:

```
...
>       always_print()
E       TypeError: always_print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capsys'
```

**Edit 1:**
Piotr's answer solved my specific issue. However, I also discovered two important caveats that I hadn't picked up in the documentation or other posts, so sharing here for others's benefit:

1. it appears that capsys.disabled() only applies to stdout and *not* stderr, which is where I was originally sending my debug messages per *nix best practice.
2. If you set a file handle to sys.stdout *before* calling capsys.disabled(), then due to the magic file discriptor mangling that pytest does, this will not work.

So, for example, you'll need to do it this way (say, if your kwargs may contain an optional "file" keyword, like the built-in print() does:

```
 fhandle = kwargs.get('file', sys.stdout) #will not work!
    with capsys.disabled():
        fhandle = kwargs.get('file', sys.stdout) #must be in context
        print(message, file=fhandle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `capsys` is a build-in fixture for tests. You should get it as a test's argument and pass it further

```
def always_print(capsys):
    with capsys.disabled():
        print('FIXME')

def test_always_print(capsys):
    always_print(capsys)
```

It will work if you run it with `pytest` command.

**Edit:**

To avoid verbosity, you can prepare some global `capsys` variable for all tests (based on the answer [how to share a variable across modules for all tests in py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768976/how-to-share-a-variable-across-modules-for-all-tests-in-py-test)):

```
# globals.py
capsys = None

# conftest.py
import pytest
import globals as gbl
from _pytest.capture import capsys

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def populate_globals(request):
    gbl.capsys = capsys(request)

# my_tests.py
import globals as gbl

def test_foo():
    with gbl.capsys.disabled():
        print('You can see me')

def test_bar():
    with gbl.capsys.disabled():
        print('You can see me too')
```

Comment: I see. Thanks.  But this means I need to add the capsys funcarg to each of my tests just to pass it down to the print_always method.  I'd rather not have to do that, as it's a lot of extra verbosity.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JJC Hello buddy, I have edited the answer and added the solution to avoid extra verbosity.

Comment: Thanks!  Using a global module is, perhaps, a bit of a kludge, but it gets the job done and avoids adding lots of noise to my test functions. I discovered two important caveats in trying to get this to work that I hadn't come across in the documentation before. I've added them.  [Dzięki Piotrze! :)]