# Removing cached files after a pytest run

Tags: python, pytest, joblib

I'm using a `joblib.Memory` to cache expensive computations when running tests with `py.test`. The code I'm using reduces to the following,

```
from joblib import Memory

memory = Memory(cachedir='/tmp/')

@memory.cache
def expensive_function(x):
    return x**2   # some computationally expensive operation here

def test_other_function():
    input_ds = expensive_function(x=10)
    ## run some tests with input_ds
```

which works fine. I'm aware this could be possibly more elegantly done with [`tmpdir_factory`](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) fixture but that's beside the point.

The issue I'm having is how to clean the cached files once all the tests run,

- is it possible to share a global variable among all tests (which would contains e.g. a list of path to the cached objects) ?
- is there a mechanism in py.test to call some command once all the tests are run (whether they succeed or not)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> is it possible to share a global variable among all tests (which would contains e.g. a list of path to the cached objects) ?

I wouldn't go down that path.  Global mutable state is something best avoided, particularly in testing.

> is there a mechanism in py.test to call some command once all the tests are run (whether they succeed or not)?

Yes, add an auto-used session-scoped fixture into your project-level `conftest.py` file:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.yield_fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def test_suite_cleanup_thing():
    # setup
    yield
    # teardown - put your command here
```

The code after the yield will be run - once - at the end of the test suite, regardless of pass or fail.

Answer (score 6):

> is it possible to share a global variable among all tests (which would
>   contains e.g. a list of path to the cached objects) ?

There are actually a couple of ways to do that, each with pros and cons. I think this SO answer sums them up quite nice - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22793013/3023841 - but for example:

```
def pytest_namespace():
     return  {'my_global_variable': 0}

def test_namespace(self):
     assert pytest.my_global_variable == 0
```

> is there a mechanism in py.test to call some command once all the tests are run (whether they succeed or not)?

Yes, py.test has [teardown](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html) functions available:

```
def setup_module(module):
    """ setup any state specific to the execution of the given module."""

def teardown_module(module):
    """ teardown any state that was previously setup with a setup_module
    method.
    """
```