# Possible to do session setup in conftest without having setup done as part of first test?

Tags: python, pytest

In my `conftest.py` file, I have something that looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def do_some_setup():
    val = thing_that_takes_a_few_mins()
    yield val
    other_thing_that_takes_a_few_mins()
```

While this works, all the output for the setup is captured as part of the first test to run. That would be fine for a function scoped setup, but doesn't make sense for a session based.

Am I doing something wrong/is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4):

You can always move the code from a session-scoped fixture to a pre-run hook, for example to [`pytest_sessionstart`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart)/[`pytest_sessionfinish`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish):

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    thing_that_takes_a_few_mins()


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    other_thing_that_takes_a_few_mins()
```

Beware though that `pytest_sessionstart` hook is called before the tests are collected, so if you need info about what tests are scheduled to run in `thing_that_takes_a_few_mins`, the hook [`pytest_runtestloop`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtestloop) will suit you better.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to get a value out of those hooks into my tests though? I updated OP slightly; thing_that_takes_a_few_mins() returns a value that I want accessible in my tests.

Comment: Sure this is doable, `pytest` provides built in caching mechanism for that - check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768976/how-to-share-a-variable-across-modules-for-all-tests-in-py-test/50611422#50611422) to the question [how to share a variable across modules for all tests in py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768976) for a working example. When looking at the other answers, keep in mind that they are outdated; sharing the data via `pytest.cache` is the preferred solution nowadays.

Comment: Looking at my other answer, you may be asking how to access `config.cache` in the hook function since the `request` fixture is not available - just use `pytest.config.cache` instead.