# Migrating form noses setup_package() to pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest, nose

right now I'm trying to convert some API tests from Nose to Pytest. When I tried to do that I faced a little problem: Pytest doesnt support the "setup_package()" functionality. The "setup_package()" is in the __init__.py file of where the tests are.

This is the directory structure:

```
tests/__init__.py
      test_001.py
      test_002.py
      ...
```

A easy solution would be to give the setup_package() function a fixture, but the problem here is, that my setup_package() is accessing a global counter in the __init__.py. So that the __ini__.py file looks like that:

```
counter_id = 0

def setup_package():
    global counter
    counter = some_function()

def teardown_package():
    global counter
    clear_object(counter_id)
```

Im pretty sure, that there is very easy solution to migrate this but as I'm new to Pytest I want to know the "pytestian" way of migrating this particular example to Pytest! My first idea was to use a fixture with params functionality, but I'm not sure if it's a good way to migrate at all.

Comment: An [autouse fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids) with a [session scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session) covers the use case of `setup_package`/`teardown_package`. If you need a recipe for having global variables in `pytest`, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768976) should help.

Comment: I tried to do:

@fixture(autouse=True, scope="package") at setup_package and teardown_package but it's not firing. Why did I do wrong?

Comment: `@pytest(scope='session', autouse=True) def my_setup_func(): counter = some_function(); yield; clear_object(counter)` replaces both `setup_package` and `teardown_package` in one fixture.

Comment: I did that already. Thanks. I got it worked when I created a conftest.py file and copied it there.

Comment: You're right - this should be packed into a `conftest` file to work project-wide, my bad!

Comment: Please feel free to answer this question, as your answer was the correct solution (even though you didn't mention the conftest file, but that was just a minor detail). Again: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @TheOnionMaster would you mind to post what you did to solve the issue as response for this question? I am facing the same problem but I had no success with conftest. Might be doing something wrong form my side, so you answer could help I think.

Comment: @lucrib Have a look at my solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hoefling already hinted in the comments:

I just created a new conftest.py (relate to [In pytest, what is the use of conftest.py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466027/in-pytest-what-is-the-use-of-conftest-py-files][1])) file in the tests directory (see initial question for the folder structure).

```
tests/__init__.py
      conftest.py
      test_001.py
      test_002.py
      ...
```

In that conftest.py file, I just copied the setup_package function in it, with the following fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def setup_and_teardown_package():
(...) #setup
yield
(...) #teardown
```

Regarding the `counter_id`: We don't need `flags` anymore, as we have a single function for our `setup` and `teardown`, so that the variables wont be lost. 
The `yield` tells the function to stop, till all the tests are done, and then to continue with the the method. So basically: Everything **BEFORE** `yield` will behave like the setup and everything **AFTER** the `yield` will behave like the teardown -> There is no need for globals anymore :)

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for this!