# in pytest how can I use command line arguments to modify test parameters?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to add a command line parameter to my tests which have effect on (but not only on) test parameters. So I've added an option to my `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--target-name", action="store")
```

I know how to make fixtures depend on command line values but not how to do this for test parameters

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "target_specific_data", json.parse(open("target-%s.json" % target_name)))
def test_foo(target_specific_data):
      ...
      ...
```

How can I do this with pytest?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html and https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/

Answer (score 1):

Pytest considers value of parameters as list of values. You can make one function which would return your data and assign to them in list at run time or make the function return the list it self as below.

conftest.py

```
import os

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--target-name", action="store")

def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.getoption('target-name'):
        os.environ["target-name"] = config.getoption('target-name')
```

test file

```
import json
import pytest
import os

def get_test_param():
    return json.parse(open("target-{}.json".format(os.getenv('target-name')))

@pytest.mark.parametrize('target_specific_data', [get_test_param()]))
def test_foo(target_specific_data):
    pass
```

Hope it would help !!

Comment: This just adds a global state (environment variables) which in my eyes is bad design. Isn't there a PyTest internal way to do this?

Comment: You can achieve that using Pytest namespace or using Pytest cache. Pytest namespace is been deprecated since version 3.2. Also you can use global variables. Here's the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768976/how-to-share-a-variable-across-modules-for-all-tests-in-py-test/50611422#50611422) having all these solution.